# How to Handle Dynamic Database Connections in Go?

Tags: postgresql, go, multiple-databases, go-echo

I am currently building a Go application that needs to connect to multiple databases dynamically.

For context I have 22 Databases (db1, db2, db3...) and the dbUser, dbPass and dbPort remains the same. To determine which database to connect to, I need access to the query param in echo before database connection.

I need a solution to connect to the right database efficiently. What are some best practices and methods for achieving this in Go?

Main.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"

    _variantHttpDelivery "backend/server/variant/delivery/http"
    _variantHttpDeliveryMiddleware "backend/server/variant/delivery/http/middleware"
    _variantRepo "backend/server/variant/repository/postgres"
    _variantUcase "backend/server/variant/usecase"
)

func init() {
    viper.SetConfigFile(`config.json`)
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if viper.GetBool(`debug`) {
        log.Println("Service RUN on DEBUG mode")
    }
}

func main() {
    dbHost := viper.GetString(`database.host`)
    dbPort := viper.GetString(`database.port`)
    dbUser := viper.GetString(`database.user`)
    dbPass := viper.GetString(`database.pass`)
    dbName := viper.GetString(`database.name`)

    connection := fmt.Sprintf("postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s", dbUser, dbPass, dbHost, dbPort, dbName)
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s?%s", connection)
    dbConn, err := sql.Open(`postgres`, dsn)
    log.Println("Connection Successful ")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = dbConn.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        err := dbConn.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    e := echo.New()
    middL := _variantHttpDeliveryMiddleware.InitMiddleware()
    e.Use(middL.CORS)
    variantRepo := _variantRepo.NewPsqlVariantRepository(dbConn)

    timeoutContext := time.Duration(viper.GetInt("context.timeout")) * time.Second
    au := _variantUcase.NewVariantUsecase(variantRepo, timeoutContext)
    _variantHttpDelivery.NewVariantHandler(e, au)

    log.Fatal(e.Start(viper.GetString("server.address"))) //nolint
}
```

Repository which handles all the database logic

```
package postgres

import (
    "backend/server/domain"
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "reflect"
)

type psqlVariantRepository struct {
    Conn *sql.DB
}

// NewPsqlVariantRepository will create an object that represent the variant.Repository interface
func NewPsqlVariantRepository(conn *sql.DB) domain.VariantRepository {
    return &psqlVariantRepository{conn}
}

func (m *psqlVariantRepository) GetByVCF(ctx context.Context, vcf string) (res domain.Variant, err error) {
    query := `SELECT * FROM main1 WHERE variant_vcf = $1`

    list, err := m.fetch(ctx, query, vcf)

    if err != nil {
        return domain.Variant{}, err
    }

    if len(list) > 0 {
        res = list[0]
    } else {
        return res, domain.ErrNotFound
    }

    return
}

func (m *psqlVariantRepository) fetch(ctx context.Context, query string, args ...interface{}) (result []domain.Variant, err error) {
    rows, err := m.Conn.QueryContext(ctx, query, args...)

    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    defer func() {
        errRow := rows.Close()
        if errRow != nil {
            logrus.Error(errRow)
        }
    }()

    result = make([]domain.Variant, 0)

    for rows.Next() {
        t := domain.Variant{}
        values := make([]interface{}, 0, reflect.TypeOf(t).NumField())
        v := reflect.ValueOf(&t).Elem()

        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            if v.Type().Field(i).Type.Kind() == reflect.String {
                values = append(values, new(sql.NullString))
            } else {
                values = append(values, v.Field(i).Addr().Interface())
            }
        }

        err = rows.Scan(values...)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Error(err)
            return nil, err
        }

        for i, value := range values {
            if ns, ok := value.(*sql.NullString); ok {
                v.Field(i).SetString(ns.String)
            }
        }

        result = append(result, t)
    }

    logrus.Info("Successfully fetched results from database ")

    return result, nil
}
```

So far I couldn't find any solution

Comment: Encapsulate the database connection, maintain `*sql.DB` link for each database name, using `map[string]*sql.DB` or other connection pool related (skip here for simplicity). And get the corresponding `*sql.DB` before querying and initialize `psqlVariantRepository` to query, which will not cause performance waste.